# Allow an end user to populate a field along with the selection fields

Tags: sap-query

I would like to add 1 input filed into the Infoset/Query in SAP.
Basically I'd like to have 1 field (integer) end user can populate alongside the selection fields. How to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add additional input fields in the Infoset edit dialog. Click on button "Extras" and then tab "Selections". You can add additional selection parameters there.

In tab "Extras" you can also add additional fields for your infoset output and add some abap logic to each field. The logic is processed in the order the fields are listed, you can change the order with the field "Sequence" in the field details. You can also add whole tables and structures in that tab.